# Why could the error term be sampled coefficient wise?

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, lattice-crypto, ring-lwe

In SEAL homomorphic encryption library, it implements the BFV and CKKS. We know the error $e\in R_q$ which is a Guassian distribution. When sampling an error term $e = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} e_ix^i$, it just samples $e_i$ from some discrete Guassain distribution over the integers.

However, it seems that the discrete Guassian distribution over high dimension lattice could not be sampled coefficient wise. What goes wrong ?